# Why I Cant install numpy

Tags: python, numpy, msys

I always get this error, it seems to be related to `python.h`, could someone help me? I am using windows for my virtual environment in python im using python 3.10.6
**

```
C:\Users\Dsnie> pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.26.0.tar.gz (15.6 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [23 lines of output]
      + C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\python.exe C:\Users\Dsnie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rmir3q3w\numpy_c2d58ccd31904cc9a4edbc91bd1755a7\vendored-meson\meson\meson.py setup C:\Users\Dsnie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rmir3q3w\numpy_c2d58ccd31904cc9a4edbc91bd1755a7 C:\Users\Dsnie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rmir3q3w\numpy_c2d58ccd31904cc9a4edbc91bd1755a7\.mesonpy-llk80wd6\build -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=C:\Users\Dsnie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rmir3q3w\numpy_c2d58ccd31904cc9a4edbc91bd1755a7\.mesonpy-llk80wd6\build\meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.2.99
      Source dir: C:\Users\Dsnie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rmir3q3w\numpy_c2d58ccd31904cc9a4edbc91bd1755a7
      Build dir: C:\Users\Dsnie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rmir3q3w\numpy_c2d58ccd31904cc9a4edbc91bd1755a7\.mesonpy-llk80wd6\build
      Build type: native build
      Project name: NumPy
      Project version: 1.26.0
      C compiler for the host machine: cc (gcc 12.2.0 "cc (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.2.0")
      C linker for the host machine: cc ld.bfd 2.39
      C++ compiler for the host machine: c++ (gcc 12.2.0 "c++ (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.2.0")
      C++ linker for the host machine: c++ ld.bfd 2.39
      Cython compiler for the host machine: cython (cython 3.0.3)
      Host machine cpu family: x86_64
      Host machine cpu: x86_64
      Program python found: YES (C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\python.exe)
      Found pkg-config: C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\pkg-config.EXE (1.8.0)
      Run-time dependency python found: YES 3.10
      Has header "Python.h" with dependency python-3.10: NO

      ..\..\meson.build:46:2: ERROR: Problem encountered: Cannot compile `Python.h`. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel

      A full log can be found at C:\Users\Dsnie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rmir3q3w\numpy_c2d58ccd31904cc9a4edbc91bd1755a7\.mesonpy-llk80wd6\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details
```

I've already tried it with commands like

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-dev
```

Comment: Did `apt install` work? I didn't know you could do that with mingw

Comment: apt doesnt run on windows... it looks like you are running under mingw ... you likely need to specify the location of python.h ... or you could just install python for windows... you might also be able to install it with --binary-only flag ....

Comment: your question is tagged with virtualenv, but you're not showing you're using one at all. Create a virtual environment using the normal Windows version of Python, _activate that_ by running `yourvenvname\Scripts\activate`, and then install numpy in that virtual environment using `python -m pip install numpy`.